# How to remove soft hypen or long dash from pyspark dataframe column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Not able to split Experience_datesEmployeed column which is having long dash. How to split the string or how to remove the long dash from column value.

I tried reading the file with UTF-8 encoding.

```
df_final=spark.read.options(header="True",inferSchema='True',delimiter=',').option("encoding", "UTF-8").csv("/path/csv")
```

Tried to split with unicode like 8212,8211,2014.

```
df_final.withColumn('Splitted', split(df_final['Experience_datesEmployeed'], u'\u2014')[0]).show()
```

**Sample CSV file**

```
  fullName,Experience_datesEmployeed,Experience_expcompany,Experience_expduraation, Experience_position
    David,Feb 1999 – Sep 2001, Foothill,2 yrs 8 mos, Marketing Assoicate
    David,1994 – 1997, abc,3 yrs,Senior Auditor
    David,Jun 2020 – Present,   Fellows INC,3 mos,Director Board
    David,2017 – Jun 2019,     Fellows INC ,2 yrs,Fellow - Class 22
    David,Sep 2001 – Present, The John D.,19 yrs, Manager
```

Comment: did you try to split with `"–"` directly ?

Comment: @Steven I tried to split with long dash "–". But this char is not printing on the Vi editor or pyspark shell.

Comment: Then the problem comes probably from you interface, not spark